# Visual Studio hangs downloading Cordova Geolocation plugin

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins

I have created a Cordova project in Visual Studio 2015. By using `cordova --version` on my project folder, I could see that I am using **Cordova 4.2.0**.

Next thing I wanted to do is installing Geolocation plugin. So I did this by editing `config.xml via VS UI. The problem is that, once I hit, "Add", VS hangs.

[image]

It stays in this condition forever.

#### Please note

I spotted other questions about people not being able to download the same plugin, but that was not VS hanging, it was VS reporting an error. The reported error should have been fixed.

FYI I installed VS2015 Enterprise (full installation).

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the tools for Apache Cordova? Have you upgraded to update 4?

Comment: Also, can you please tell me if you are behind a proxy server?

Comment: @MichaelBraude: I am not sure about that actually. So there is an update 4 for VS2015? I'll try and see. About being behind a proxy... I do not think so. I am connected with my home Internet, and my http requests are not being processed by a proxy

Comment: As you can see from the updated answer, Cordova version is not the latest. How to update it through VS? Or should I go use `cordova` commands from my project folder? I am afraid that doing this might screw up VS configuration or doing some damage to my project....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it just takes **a lot of time**! I left Visual Studio in that state for 4 hours. And now I have the plug-in downloaded and everything is fine!

It is pretty strange though. My network was fine and up during all the time. However it might be some network issue concerning me. Unfortunately hard to say.

So basically the procedure is fine. If anybody else runs into this again, then i think Visual Studio is having troubles downloading these plug-ins.